# Error in Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 the error persist

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, xampp

I don't really know what wrong a while ago; it's still working, but then it's just causing an error:

```
$query = "insert into subject values($newstd,'" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['subname'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['subdesc'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['recommendation1'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['recommendation2'], ENT_QUOTES) . "',NULL)";
```

The structure of my Database is

```
subid
subname
sudesc
recommendation1
recommendation2
```

When I run the Query I always got that kind of error.

Comment: What you really need to do is post an actual example query that is failing.  Also, you should be using mysqli_real_escape_string or similar; http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: We'd also need the table structure.. SHOW CREATE TABLE subject;

Answer (score 0):

you are having 5 columns in table, and inserting six columns value. Why inserting 'Null' value at last.. there is no column for it